# Using .NET analyzer rule CA1001 for components of a framework which does not use IDisposable

Tags: c#, .net, unity-game-engine, static-analysis, dispose

I have a Unity project with Roslyn analyzers enabled, one of them is CA1001: "Types that own disposable fields should be disposable" (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/fundamentals/code-analysis/quality-rules/ca1001).

This comes in handy for classes which are created and destroyed manually, to see if they properly dispose all of their fields. However in a lot of cases due to the viral nature of IDisposable the topmost objects creating these will be components, MonoBehaviour classes in the case of Unity. To satisfy the rule one would add IDisposable to the MonoBehaviour and implement the dispose pattern properly, however that does not add much value to the class, as being component of a framework which does not rely on IDisposable it will never be called.

What would seem to be the best in this case is to alter the rule somehow to check if IDisposable fields have been disposed in the OnDestroy method. Is there a way to change rule CA1001 to work like this for MonoBehaviour subclasses? Or is there any other analyzer which can do this? If not then at least could the rule be disabled for subclasses of a specific type? (The best I could do so far is to suppress the rule for files named "*Component.cs" but that's far from best.)

My question is targeted toward Unity but it actually applies to any framework not relying on the IDisposable interface.

#### Edit:

Example code:

```cs
public class Resource : IDisposable
{
    public void Dispose()
    {
        Debug.Log("Resource disposed");
    }
}

public class ExampleComponent : MonoBehaviour
{
    private Resource resource;

    private void Start()
    {
        resource = new Resource();
    }

    private void OnDestroy()
    {
        resource.Dispose();
    }
}
```

In this case `resource` is properly disposed in the conventional `OnDestroy` method but CA1001 is still triggered.

Comment: Just a quick headsup - I vaguely remember Jetbrains' Resharper dealing with this in some way although I'm not sure about the details. There is a resharper unity plugin. Also - the text is quite clear but a piece of code / screengrab to show what you mean would complement this nicely. Also - roslyn analyzers are suprisingly easy to make so there's always that route :)

Answer (score 0):

I think you could ignore the rule for any type derived from `UnityEngine.MonoBehaviour` via [Exclude specific types and their derived types](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/fundamentals/code-analysis/quality-rules/ca1001#exclude-specific-types-and-their-derived-types) (in the very same link you posted)

> add the following key-value pair to an `.editorconfig` file in your project

something like

```
dotnet_code_quality.CA1001.excluded_type_names_with_derived_types = T:UnityEngine.MonoBehaviour
```

Comment: Strangely it doesn't work. I've tried it with all combinations of "T:", "~T:", and without prefix; and "UnityEngine.MonoBehaviour", and "ExampleComponent", with restarts of Visual Studio and Unity between them. Also tried it without Unity, in a simple Visual Studio .NET Core console project, same result, no effect. (Visual Studio 2019, .NET Analyzers 5.0.3)

Comment: Even though CA1001's page mentions it, the generic Code Quality Rule Options page (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/fundamentals/code-analysis/code-quality-rule-options) only lists CA1303 as an option for `excluded_type_names_with_derived_types`. This may not be related though, it could be just an incomplete page.

Comment: @LostLont to be honest I have no experience with Roslyn whatsoever ^^ I was just citing the documenting ... To me it also sounds strange since this is explicitly mentioned in this rule's specific documentation page .. why would they do that if it is only working for a specific rule anyway? ^^ .. but than again .. it's Microsoft so ... :'D